# Convert list of numeric vectors into data frame and write number in sequence

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rbind

How do i convert a list of lists in to a single data frame retaining the list name and then add the number of the sequence.

str(data) gives me this:

```
List of 230
 $ data_1  : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0204 0.0516 0.0924 0.1424 0.2044 ...
 $ data_14 : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.006 0.0144 0.0272 0.0456 0.0712 ...
 $ data_2  : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0292 0.0736 0.1316 0.202 0.286 ...
 $ data_27 : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0056 0.0136 0.024 0.0384 0.0572 ...
 $ data_46 : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0164 0.0408 0.0716 0.11 0.1588 ...
 $ data_510: num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0128 0.034 0.0652 0.1112 0.1756 ...
 $ data_13  : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0064 0.0136 0.022 0.0332 0.046 ...
 $ data_19  : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0036 0.0096 0.0224 0.0444 0.0776 ...
 $ data_080: num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0056 0.0132 0.0228 0.0356 0.052 ...
 $ data_15 : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0028 0.0068 0.0116 0.0172 0.0244 ...
 $ data_18 : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0008 0.0012 0.0024 0.0032 0.0044 0.0064 0.0096 0.014 0.02 0.0268 ...
 $ data_3  : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0124 0.0308 0.0576 0.0932 0.1384 ...
 $ data_33 : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0036 0.0084 0.016 0.0252 0.0372 ...
 $ data_500: num [1:19, 1:2] 0.004 0.0096 0.0196 0.0372 0.0648 ...
 $ data_015 : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0072 0.0172 0.03 0.0456 0.064 ...
 $ data_02  : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0132 0.0296 0.0484 0.0696 0.0936 ...
 $ data_04  : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0072 0.0192 0.038 0.0692 0.1132 ...
 $ data_37  : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0056 0.014 0.0252 0.0388 0.0552 ...
 $ data_4   : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.0072 0.0188 0.0352 0.056 0.0812 ...
 $ data_550 : num [1:19, 1:2] 0.004 0.0104 0.02 0.032 0.048 ...
```

... the list is repeated from 2 to 30 times

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
ID  Area    Size    Interval
data_1  0.0204  0.1     1
data_1  0.0516  0.15    1
data_1  0.0924  0.2     1
data_1  0.1424  0.25    1
data_14 0.006   0.1     1
data_14 0.0144  0.15    1
data_14 0.0272  0.2     1
data_14 0.0456  0.25    1
data_1  0.0204  0.1     1
data_1  0.0516  0.15    1
data_1  0.0924  0.2     1
data_1  0.1424  0.25    1
data_14 0.006   0.1     1
data_14 0.0144  0.15    1
data_14 0.0272  0.2     1
data_14 0.0456  0.25    1
data_1  0.0254  0.1     2
data_1  0.0566  0.15    2
data_1  0.0974  0.2     2
data_1  0.1474  0.25    2
data_14 0.011   0.1     2
data_14 0.0194  0.15    2
data_14 0.0322  0.2     2
data_14 0.0506  0.25    2
data_1  0.0254  0.1     2
data_1  0.0566  0.15    2
data_1  0.0974  0.2     2
data_1  0.1474  0.25    2
data_14 0.011   0.1     2
data_14 0.0194  0.15    2
data_14 0.0322  0.2     2
data_14 0.0506  0.25    2
```

i have tried `lapply(data, data.frame)` and `do.call(rbind.data.frame, data)`

But is not quite working the way i want it to...

Comment: What do you mean by `write number in sequence`?

Comment: Suppose, the first ID is `data_1`, second set of rows is `data_4`  and third is again `data_1`, what will be the sequence?

Comment: In the updated dataset, it is not clear how the `interval` is assigned.

Comment: It's a list of numeric vectors, not "a list of lists"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Loop over the `list`, convert to `data.frame`, use `rbindlist` to vertically bind the data.frames in the `list` (the option `idcol=TRUE` ensure that a separate column is created based on the `names` of the `list`.  We can use `rle` from `base R` along with `ave` to create a 'Seq' column for duplicate '.id' values that are not adjacent.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(data, as.data.frame), idcol=TRUE)[, Seq :=inverse.rle(within.list(rle(.id), 
                 values <- ave(values, values, FUN=seq_along)))][]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we do the vertical binding with `bind_rows`, create a grouping variable ('grp') based on whether the adjacent 'ID' values are same or  not.

```
library(dplyr)
dM1 <- lapply(data, as.data.frame) %>% 
                bind_rows(., .id = "ID") %>%
                mutate(grp = cumsum(ID!= lag(ID, default="999")))
```

We get the `unique` rows of 'ID' and 'grp' selected above data, grouped by 'ID', create a sequence column with `row_number()` and do a `right_join`.

```
dM1 %>%
   select(ID, grp) %>% 
   unique() %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(Seq = row_number())  %>%
   right_join(., dM1)  %>%
   select(-grp)
```

---

#### Update

Or a more easier approach would be to get the sequence grouped by the `names` of the `list` (i.e. 'data'), change the `names` by `paste`ing the sequence with the original names, convert the `list` of matrices to `list` of data.frames by looping through the `list` with `lapply`, bind the rows (`bind_rows`) specifying the `.id`, and `separate` the 'ID' column into two.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
names(data) <- paste(names(data), ave(names(data), names(data),
                     FUN= seq_along), sep=",")

lapply(data, as.data.frame) %>%
        bind_rows(., .id = "ID") %>%
        separate(ID, into = c("ID", "Seq"), sep=",")
```

Comment: Looks almost ok, How do I obtain the Interval (a new column added) with the information of what number of the repeated ID it comes from (first, second, third a.s.o as number 1,2,3...)

Comment: @Vestlink It would have been better if you showed a small reproducible example with expected output

Comment: your data.table update did the trick. You beat me by a few secs :-)

Comment: I may have overlooked something in this. How do add the lapply generated "ID" and "Seq" to the data?

Comment: @Vestlink I am not sure what you meant,   In the update the `separate` step creates the 'ID' and 'Seq' columns.  Here the `data` is a `list` of data.frames.

Comment: I was thinking that one might be able to somthing like this **data@data <- lapply(data, as.data.frame) %>%
        bind_rows(., .id = "ID") %>%
        separate(ID, into = c("ID", "Seq"), sep=",")**

Comment: @Vestlink The `separate` output is a `data.frame`.  The `bind_rows` creaed a single dataset from all the list of data.frame.  So, it is better to have it as a new object i.e. `data1 <- lapply(data, ....`

Comment: I see. what if i wanted to add to new columns and not pasting like in this **names(data) <- paste(names(data), ave(names(data), names(data),
                     FUN= seq_along), sep=",")** That is create two new columns "ID" and "Seq" data$ID and data$Seq

Comment: @Vestlink If you want to keep the `list` of `data.frames` as such, then don't do the `bind_rows` step.  Instead we can have `Map(cbind, lapply(data, as.data.frame), ID = names(data), Seq = ave(names(data), names(data),  
                     FUN= seq_along))`  Here the `names(data)` is the original names of the data and not the `names(data) <- paste(...`